# How to differentiate between buttons in a ListView

Tags: java, android, button, android-listview

I want to make a list of connections and give user a option to connect to any one of them.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="connect"
    android:text="connect" />
```

This is the basic structure of each item in the list. After creating the list, in "connect" function, I am not able not figure out which button in the list called it. I have to know that to get connected to that particular connection. Can anyone please help me out to know the position of the button clicked? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could let each button use a different function onclick. Each of these functions could in essence just call your connect function with a parameter so that you know which button it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the onClick event in your custom adapter's getView method.

```
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vehicals_details_row, parent,
                        false);
    Button btnView = (Button)  row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnView .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
           // Your code that you want to execute on this button click
       }

    });
```

For more info Check the link [Handling Button clicks in a ListView Row](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.it/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add an [`OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) to the `ListView` using [`setOnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29). The listener has the following callback function:

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

(`position` is what you want, i guess)

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two choices:

1) In the adapter, attach to every button (in the view) a listener, referring to the correct item in your list (I assume the items are instances of the (invented) class ConnectionItem):

```
 View itemView = .... //view inflated here
 ConnectionItem  connItem = ..//the current connection
 Button button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View v) {
           Log.i(YOUR_TAG, "clicked on item:"+connectionItem.getName());
      }
 });
```

2) In the adapter, you set a tag to the view with the item itself:

```
 View itemView = .... //view inflated here
 ConnectionItem  connItem = ..//the current connection
 Button button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
 button.setTag(connItem)
```

Then in your activity:

```
 public void connect(View view) {
        ConnectionItem  connItem = (ConnectionItem)view.getTag();
        Log.i(YOUR_TAG, "clicked on item:"+connectionItem.getName());
 }
```

Hope this helps